# MultiThreading inside recursive nested directory while deleting it

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, parallel-processing, java-8

> 1. I am trying to delete a very big nested directory structure having multiple files and subdirectory inside it. Each subdirectory can have multiple file and subdirectory inside it.
> 2. So we can only delete a file or an empty directory here. If a directory is not empty and has further files and subdirectory, list those subdir and files and delete them in recursion.
> 3. I have written a pseudo code here and used a parallel stream to delete the list in recursion.

```
class A {
    boolean mainDeletemethod(obj){
        boolean finalStatus = false;
          if(obj.type == file){
             deleteAPI(obj);
              finalStatus = true;
          } //if ends
          else if(obj.type==directory){
             if(obj.message.recursive == true) { //inner if
                boolean status =   deleteDirectoryAPI(obj)
                   if(!status)
                      return status
                } //inner if ends
             else{ // empty directory, delete it, deleteDir would take care of that, inner else loop 
                   deleteDir(obj)
                      finalStatus = true;
                 } //inner else ends
          }//else if ends
    return finalStatus;
    } //mainDeletemethod ends

    boolean deleteDirectoryAPI(Object obj){
            list<Object> results = listAPI(obj) //results would have subdirectories and files inside it
    //trying to parallelize the deletion of files and directory
        boolean stat =result
                    .stream()
                    .parallel()
                    .map(fileObject -> {
                        boolean individualStatus = null;
                        try {
                            individualStatus = deleteParallel(obj);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            _log.error("Error", e);
                            return individualStatus;
                        }
                        return true;
                    })
                    .filter(status-> status != true)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Status.OK);

        if(stat!=true){
            return stat;
        }
    } // deleteDirectoryAPI ends


    boolean deleteParallel(obj) {
        boolean status = mainDeletemethod(obj);
        if(status)
            return status;
        return false; 
    } //deleteParallel ends

} //Class A ends
```

There are some problems I am stuck here in this code

```
.filter(status-> status != true)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Status.OK);
```

> 1. This code above makes the stream to wait until all subtasks are complete. It holds the thread in the default executor. When all threads in the executor are exhausted by waiting here in sequence of the recursive call would it get stuck?
> 2. I suppose this is making my parent task to wait on all the subtasks(in recursion where in a scenario we have deep directory/file structure) to wait and can cause deadlock incase my threadpool gets exhausted. Can my threadpool be exhausted here?
> 3. I do not want to wait on individual recursive subtasks to return me a status and check for it rather want to implement it through some global Atomic variable which is set to false if any one of my subtasks fails and return it. I may have multiple delete tasks so a Map of Atomic variable is something needed here which can keep a track of all the scheduled task.

Comment: I'm not sure that a multi-threaded approach will give you much advantage. The bottleneck is likely to be the physical storage media, and that's going to make your deletes (which is just another form of writing to disk) sequential no matter what.

Comment: I can confirm what @bazza comments. You will only make things worst by multithreading file deletions if this is a SSD or HDD

Comment: Technically what both of you are saying make sense and should be the case but somehow I am achieving a better performance in a multithreaded environment here. I am not aware of underlying server side implementation as in how its managing delete, but what I am trying to achieve here is to pass multithreaded requests to delete objects to the server.

Comment: You should rethink the way you’re working with `boolean` values. Don’t use obsolete comparisons like `… == true` or constants like `Status.OK`, which require me to guess that it is just `true`. Neither use `… != true`; you already know about `! …`. Besides that, you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how streams work, of course, the initiating thread will eventually wait for the completion of all sub-tasks, but it also participates in the evaluation.

Comment: Likewise, instead of `.map(function returning boolean) .filter(status-> status != true) .findFirst() .orElse(Status.OK);`, you can simply write `.allMatch(function returning boolean);`

Comment: I am still new to stream. But from the testing I see that we would have main thread and then coworker Threads from the ForkJoinCommon pool to do a task. So a task in my case is `list(All children of parent directory) ->Put it in a List -> Read an entry from the list -> recursively create a function stack of list() and delete() operation till we reach the leaf node for that particular directory -> when leaf found execute delete and return the status of deleting it to parent function till end of recursive stack -> Free the thread for next Task.` Whats a subtask here that this thread does?

Comment: So if I am deleting a List having n numbers using a stream.parallel() so in a 8 core processor, it will have 1 main thread and 7 threads from Fork joinCommonPool. As you said the main thread would participate too here. The `task` here is to delete the complete list and the `subtasks` would be each thread deleting a single number from the list in parallel 8 at a time? So my question here was would the code `.filter(status-> !status)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(true);` makes my `subtasks` to wait on each other to complete and then take a new subtask.